# Need help to clean my code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a newbie in coding javascript and jquery, to be honest there is a lot of things i don't understand but i always manage to make things work, thanks to this wonderful community.
I wrote something for a project but i'm sure it's not as clean and organized as it could be, everything work but i would like it to be as clean as possible.  If anyone has suggestions or comments about how to clean/improve the code below that would be awesome.
By the way, sorry for my bad english. THANKS !

```js
// SCROLL
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.scrollTo').click(function() { // Au clic sur un élément
    var page = $(this).attr('href'); // Page cible
    var speed = 8500; // Durée de l'animation (en ms)
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(page).offset().top
    }, speed); // Go
    return false;
  });
});

//INTRO
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() < 200) {
    $('#clic').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('#clic').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
  }
});

//OPACITE
var divs = $('#jour');
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var percent = $(document).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height());
  divs.css('opacity', 1 - percent);
});

//STARS
$(document).ready(function() {
  var animationStarted = false;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10000 && !animationStarted) {
      $("#stars1").animate({
        "right": "+=3000px"
      }, 4000);
      animationStarted = true;
    };
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 10000 && animationStarted) {
      $("#stars1").animate({
        "right": "-=3000px"
      }, 4000);
      animationStarted = false;
    };
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  var animationStarted = false;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10600 && !animationStarted) {
      $("#stars2").animate({
        "right": "+=3000px"
      }, 4000);
      animationStarted = true;
    };
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 10600 && animationStarted) {
      $("#stars2").animate({
        "right": "-=3000px"
      }, 4000);
      animationStarted = false;
    };
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  var animationStarted = false;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 11000 && !animationStarted) {
      $("#stars3").animate({
        "right": "+=3000px"
      }, 5000);
      animationStarted = true;
    };
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 11000 && animationStarted) {
      $("#stars3").animate({
        "right": "-=3000px"
      }, 5000);
      animationStarted = false;
    };
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  var animationStarted = false;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 11600 && !animationStarted) {
      $("#stars4").animate({
        "right": "+=3000px"
      }, 5000);
      animationStarted = true;
    };
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 11600 && animationStarted) {
      $("#stars4").animate({
        "right": "-=3000px"
      }, 5000);
      animationStarted = false;
    };
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  var animationStarted = false;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50 && !animationStarted) {
      $("#dcw").animate({
        "left": "+=3000px"
      }, 3000);
      animationStarted = true;
    };
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 50 && animationStarted) {
      $("#dcw").animate({
        "left": "-=3000px"
      }, 3000);
      animationStarted = false;
    };
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  var animationStarted = false;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1000 && !animationStarted) {
      $("#dcw2").animate({
        "left": "+=3000px"
      }, 3000);
      animationStarted = true;
    };
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 1000 && animationStarted) {
      $("#dcw2").animate({
        "left": "-=3000px"
      }, 3000);
      animationStarted = false;
    };
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  var animationStarted = false;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 5000 && !animationStarted) {
      $("#dcw3").animate({
        "left": "+=3000px"
      }, 3000);
      animationStarted = true;
    };
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 5000 && animationStarted) {
      $("#dcw3").animate({
        "left": "-=3000px"
      }, 3000);
      animationStarted = false;
    };
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
 background: #c7d6ee; /* Old browsers */
 /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
 background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #c7d6ee 0%, #000911 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#c7d6ee), color-stop(100%,#000911)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #c7d6ee 0%,#000911 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #c7d6ee 0%,#000911 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #c7d6ee 0%,#000911 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #c7d6ee 0%,#000911 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c7d6ee', endColorstr='#000911',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
 max-height: 30000px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
}
a:visited { text-decoration: none; color:white; }
a:hover { text-decoration: none; color:white; }
a:focus { text-decoration: none; color:white; }
a:hover, a:active { text-decoration: none; color:white; }
h1, h2, h3 {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}
#clic img{
 max-width: 100px;
}
#clic{
 top: 0;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 11;
 background: #000000;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 padding-top: 15%;
}
#dcw{
 position: fixed;
 color: #ffffff;
 z-index: 12;
 top: 30px;
 left: -2950px;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 border-top: 3px solid;
}
#dcw2{
 position: fixed;
 color: #ffffff;
 z-index: 12;
 top: 55px;
 left: -2950px;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
#dcw3{
 position: fixed;
 color: #ffffff;
 z-index: 12;
 top: 95px;
 left: -2950px;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 border-bottom: 3px solid;
}

#dcw p{
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-weight: bold;
}
#dcw2 p{
 font-size: 2em;
 font-weight: bold;
}
#dcw3 p{
 font-size: 2em;
 font-weight: bold;
 
}
#clic h1 h2 {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
}

#jour {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0px;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 z-index: 10;
}
#nuit {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0px;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 z-index: 9;
}
#bottom {
 margin-top: 29990px;
}
.stars {
 bottom: 100px;
 right: -3000px;
 position: fixed;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>DCW</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" type="text/css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,800italic,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="dcw">
    <p>DCW éditions vous souhaite</p>
  </div>
  <div id="dcw2">
    <p>un joyeux noël</p>
  </div>
  <div id="dcw3">
    <p>et une très belle année 2015</p>
  </div>
  <div id="clic"><a class="scrollTo" href="#bottom"><h3>GREETINGS FROM</h3><img src="img/logo_dcw.png"><h2>cliquez ou scrollez</h2><h1>&#8615;</h1> </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img id="jour" src="img/jour2.png">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img id="nuit" src="img/nuit2.png">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img id="stars1" class="stars" src="img/stars1.png">
    <img id="stars2" class="stars" src="img/stars2.png">
    <img id="stars3" class="stars" src="img/stars3.png">
    <img id="stars4" class="stars" src="img/stars_logo.png">
  </div>
  <div id="bottom"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You might have more luck over on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Can you drop it in jsbin, jsfiddle or some thing similar?

Comment: A suggestion I received 15 years ago: "Start from scratch. Use the parts that work. Add more code as you need. Keep an eye on code duplication."

Comment: Please migrate this question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a code review request, so should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Heres some tips:**

You don't need to keep calling document.ready, just do it once. Its
   only to make sure all of the DOM elements are loaded, so it will only
   ever    need to be called once.

Your scroll function is always listening for the mouse page scroll,    so calling it multiple times doesnt make any difference.    You can
   put    it all in one block.

Declare all of your variables at the top to keep them organised.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var divs = $('#jour');
  var percent = $(document).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height());
  var animationStarted = false;

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 200) {
      $('#clic').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('#clic').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
    }

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10000 && !animationStarted) {
      $("#stars1").animate({
        "right": "+=3000px"
      }, 4000);
      animationStarted = true;
    };

    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 10000 && animationStarted) {
      $("#stars1").animate({
        "right": "-=3000px"
      }, 4000);
      animationStarted = false;
    };

  });
  divs.css('opacity', 1 - percent);
});
```

Everything else looks pretty good to me!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like normal javascript to me. I guess some of messiness might be attributed to all the brackets and parenthesis that occur when doing functional programming. There are languages that compile into javascript. You might want to have a look at those if you are looking for something "cleaner". F.ex dart programming language.

Answer (score 0):

I will not comment much but atleast suggest something.

For your JavaScript code

1. Make all `$(document).ready()` code in single `$(document).ready()` function
2. Write common code in function
3. Include external JavaScript in proper places (You have written JavaScript above `DOCTYPE`)
4. Never over-comment code. only use specific comments
5. Make CSS clean like common css for same buttons, inputs. don't use css for every single button, element.

Other things you can learn by time...